# Using lists to create dynamic blocks in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have some object-type variable with one field I need to create several blocks being a list of string (var.kubernetes_worker_group_spec.zones):

```
kubernetes_worker_group_spec    = ({
    node_count = 1
    platform    = "standard-v2"
    cores       = 8
    core_fraction   = 100
    memory      = 16
    gpus        = 0
    disk_type   = "network-ssd"
    disk_size   = 100
    nat     = false
    preemptible = false
    subnet_ids  = ["someid","someid2","someid3"]
    zones       = ["ru-central1-a", "ru-central1-b", "ru-central1-c"]
    labels      = {env = "SETMEUP"}
    taints      = ["env=SETMEUP:NoSchedule"]
    unsafe_sysctls  = ["net.core.somaxconn"]
    serial_is_enabled = 0
})
```

Now some resource requires declaring of several "location" blocks with zone names:

```
resource "yandex_kubernetes_node_group" "some_node_group {
  blahblahblah

  allocation_policy {
    location {
      zone = "ru-central1-a"
    }
  }
   blahblahblah
}
```

So I want several `location` blocks formed from list subnet_ids but it looks like only `for_each` used for dynamic blocks creation, but it's impossible to use it with list.

I think it should be something like:

```
  allocation_policy {
    dynamic location {
      for l in var.kubernetes_worker_group_spec.zones
      content {
        zone            = var.kubernetes_worker_group_spec.zones[l]
      }
    }
  }
```

but this ofc won't work as for expression is used a bit differently...
Maybe there are some workarounds... Any help is appreciated! =)

Comment: A `dynamic` block `for_each` can accept any collection type, including lists. Perhaps you are thinking of resource-level `for_each`, which is different because it needs to provide a unique identifier for each instance. Dynamic blocks don't have that constraint because nested blocks are not distinct objects with their own tracking identifiers.

Comment: Yes, you were right, I was able to use for_each and get value from the list. I never thought TF has different behavior for different "for_each" usage...